# Changing a currency output - string manipulation in R

Tags: r

I am scraping some information from a website via rvest in R. The item I am scraping is displayed as two types like "450 Th. €" or "120,00 Mill. €". I want to change this into a numeric value but my calculations change depending on if its a Th. or a Mill. output. Ideally I change "450 Th. €" to 450000 and "120,00 Mill. €" to 120000000.

My current scraping code is this for this item.

```
> Value <- PlayerScrape %>%
+     html_nodes(".marktwert a") %>%
+     html_text()
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: What `rvest` has to do with your question? You have a string and want to coerce it to a number according to some logic. Post the string you are getting and the desired output. Change also the title to the question, since it's not `rvest` related.

Comment: Done - thanks for advice